# MUI: Does root element mean outer or inner element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

From this quote of official Doc (https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/api/#spread):

> **Spread**
>
> Props supplied to a component which are not explicitly documented are spread to the root element; for instance, the `className` prop is applied to the root.
>
> Now, let's say you want to disable the ripples on the `MenuItem`. You can take advantage of the spread behavior:
>
> `<MenuItem disableRipple />`
>
> The `disableRipple` prop will flow this way: `MenuItem` > `ListItem` > `ButtonBase`.

It looks like “Props” are spread to the root element, which is the inner-most element, the `ButtonBase`.

But from the Glossary (https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/api/#glossary):

### **Glossary**

- **host component**: a DOM node type in the context of `react-dom`, e.g. a `'div'`. See also [React Implementation Notes](https://reactjs.org/docs/implementation-notes.html#mounting-host-elements).
- **host element**: a DOM node in the context of `react-dom`, e.g. an instance of `window.HTMLDivElement`.
- **outermost**: The first component when reading the component tree from top to bottom i.e. breadth-first search.
- **root component**: the outermost component that renders a host component.
- **root element**: the outermost element that renders a host component.

It looks like root == outermost.

So what am I confused on?

When the `disableRipple` prop flow this way:

`MenuItem` > `ListItem` > `ButtonBase`,

is `ButtonBase` considered to be inner-most of outer-most?

is `ButtonBase` considered to be root?